# Drupal: Ubecart.. starting to use it

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

What kind of things do I need to know before to start to use Drupal Ubecart ?

I'm already experienced with Drupal.
I was wondering if I need to setup secure https connection, or doing additional work for my webshop.

Or can I just install ubecart and configure it ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a sense of how to use Ubercart, you can certainly install it on a development server and start going through the customization settings.  For production, though, definitely consider installing a SSL certificate and using [this module](http://drupal.org/project/uc_ssl) to secure the appropriate pages. And you'll need to determine which payment gateways to employ (credit cards, Paypal, Authorize.net, etc.), and set up the appropriate accounts so that when you configure Ubercart payment gateways, you can provide the needed information.

If you have some time after getting to know basic Ubercart, you might check out the [Ubercart contributions page](http://www.ubercart.org/contrib) for more ideas of what you can do.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer. Do I need access to server configuration to install a SSL certificate ? Do I need to buy specific hosting services for e-commerce, in which SSL certificate is enabled ? Consider that I usually don't have access to apache / Microsoft IIS configuration files.

Comment: Even if you don't have access to the config files, your hosting company will and can generally assist with SSL certificate installation.  (Do you have access to a control panel like Plesk?  I've installed SSL via Plesk before.)  One more thing, be sure you have a dedicated IP address available.  Lots of info available on SSL via Google on this process, e.g. http://ezinearticles.com/?How-to-Install-SSL---SSL-Certificate-Tips&id=1604784

Comment: ok,so if I've a shared IP address, some other website sharing the same ip with me could cause security issues ?

Comment: From everything I've read, a dedicated IP address is a requirement for SSL, not an option (i.e. it won't work otherwise).  Note that that's different than a dedicated server -- you could be on a shared server but still get your own IP address.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I found about using ubercart was that it was a pain to override theme. It wants to make all these horrendous looking tables, making it fit in with the rest of the site was pretty horrible.
Also, if you want to get the most out of it, install it on a local machine and take some time to explore the interface - there are a LOT of options there and it can take a while to get your head around how it fits together.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a quick payment solution for payments and can't really be bothered with ssl and all the payment issues, Paypal IPN is a godsend. This is the paypal option where the customer goes to the Paypal site to complete checkout. This is quite a bit simpler to implement than the other payment options and gets around the most important security issues, by not collecting any financial info on your site.